# Crossmerge/cascade two tables using awk or sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two tables in a same file

```
**Table A**
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15

**Table B**
a b c d e 
f g h i j 
k l m n o
```

I would like to merge it as:

```
1   a  2   b  3   c  4   d   5   e
6   f  7   g  8   h  9   i   10  j 
11  k  12  l  13  m  14  n   15  o
```

I am not sure what the right word for this kind of merging or combining is? I tried 'cascading' and 'merging in between' I got zero output from google. Sorry english is not my first language

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My first plan is to make two different text files and combine them using column identifiers. but if there is a n easier way please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: `awk` is the way to go. Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: for the `** Table X**` lines ... are those literal asterisks? will these lines always contain the string `Table`?

Comment: will all data lines have 5 values or could the number vary? will all tables (in a given file) have the same number of values in their associated data lines?

Comment: will a file always consist of *only* two tables, or could there be more than two tables in a file?

Comment: @markp-fuso No. table names are normally strings no numbers. 2 tables always. But number of rows vary all the time. but it remains same for both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk `./merge-tables.awk` script:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # Set Output Field Separator
    OFS = "\t"
}

# New table
/^\*\*.*\*\*$/ {
    # Increment table number
    ntable += 1
    # RAZ line number
    nline = 0
    # Next line
    next
}
# Ignore empty/blanks line
/^ *$/ {
    next
}

# Memorise first table
ntable == 1 {
    i = 1
    nline += 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        table[nline "/" i] = $i
        i += 1
    }
}

# Print first table element followed by second table element
ntable == 2 {
    i = 1
    nline += 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        e1 = table[nline "/" i]
        e2 = $i
        printf("%s%s%s%s", e1, OFS, e2, (i<NF)?OFS:"")
        i += 1
    }
    print ""
}
```

Executable with:

```bash
chmod +x ./merge-tables.awk
```

Run like that:

```bash
./merge-tables.awk tables.txt
```

Output:

```
1   a   2   b   3   c   4   d   5   e
6   f   7   g   8   h   9   i   10  j
11  k   12  l   13  m   14  n   15  o
```

## New version

Difference with previous: Ignore table name (surrounded or not with `**`). The empty line is considered as the table separator

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # Set Output Field Separator
    OFS = "\t"
    ntable += 1
}

# Ignore empty/blanks line
/^ *$/ {
    ntable += 1
    # RAZ line number
    nline = 0
    # Next line
    next
}

# Squeeze first line (table name)
ntable == 1 && nline == 0 {
    nline += 1
    next
}
# Memorise first table
ntable == 1 {
    i = 1
    nline += 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        table[nline "/" i] = $i
        i += 1
    }
}

# Squeeze first line (table name)
ntable == 2 && nline == 0 {
    nline += 1
    next
}
# Print first table element followed by second table element
ntable == 2 {
    i = 1
    nline += 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        e1 = table[nline "/" i]
        e2 = $i
        printf("%s%s%s%s", e1, OFS, e2, (i<NF)?OFS:"")
        i += 1
    }
    print ""
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your time and answer. I tried it with a text file with 2 tables but did not give any output.

Comment: This solution (as well as mine) expects the table names to be surrounded by asterisks, as shown in your example. That's why there's no output.

Comment: @ash, in the new version, the empty line is considered as the table separator

Answer (score 2):

In `jq`, just for fun:

```bash
jq -nrR '[inputs|split("\\s+";"")|map(select(.!=""))]
  | map(select(length>0))
  | [.[1:length/2], .[length/2+1:]]
  | transpose[] | transpose | flatten | @tsv' \
  file.txt \
| column -ts $'\t'
```

Output:

```
1   a  2   b  3   c  4   d  5   e
6   f  7   g  8   h  9   i  10  j
11  k  12  l  13  m  14  n  15  o
```

Explanation: we split each input line by whitespaces, and remove all empty fields (created by empty lines or trailing whitespace). Then we collect the result into an array, to get a 2D array of fields. After filtering out empty lines, we split the array in the middle (ignoring the table headers), transpose it, transpose every component of the result, flatten each resulting array of pairs, and convert them to tsv format. Then pipe the resulting tsv to `column`, to get the desired output formatting.

Edit: modified the script to work with any table names, not only with ones that are surrounded by asterisks (like in the example).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU paste, sed and column):

```
paste filea fileb |
sed -E 'G;:a;s/^(\S+)\s?(.*\t)(\S+)\s?(.*\n.*)/\2\4\1 \3 /;ta;s/..(.*)./\1/' |
column -t
```

Append each line of filea to each line of fileb, separated by a tab.

Pipe the result into a sed invocation.

For each  line in the result of the above, append a newline and using loop with substitution, pair up fields from either side of the tab and move them to the other side of the introduced newline. Then remove the tab, newline and a final introduced space.

Pipe the above result into an invocation of column and using the `-t` option evenly space the columns.